# Amazon Nodejs webserver

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I'm getting stuck here, so i have an amazon ec2 (standard redhat server) host up and working. i can connect to it personally no problem, however it cannot be connected to outside of my ip.

I've checked the rules and i have port 80 and 3000 open to 0.0.0.0/0 to be able to communicate, however outside of my computer (and computers in this network) i can not connect.

Everything I've found is about connecting to ssh which works fine, i have no rules in iptables, i haven't dealt much with them before, but since i can connect to the service i don't think its the issue.

summary:
Web server is running, i can connect from my computer to it, and any others in my local network, but nothing outside of it works.

i do have httpd installed as well as a simple forward from the browser to port 3000, however i cant connect to it either from outside my network.

Comment: It's running on port 80 on the server? Are you sure you have the correct port open in the security group?

Answer (score 0):

so this is a new one for me, the dns forwarding works in houst, but not outside. so inside and outside here, i can use IP address to connect, but inside only i can connect with my dns lookup. not sure what caused this, but its not an amazon problem at least. going to look at that side.